# Unitary space, inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the space of all complex-valued functions continuous on an interval $[a, b]$ becomes a unitary space if we define an inner product by the formula

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^bw(t)f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$$

where $w$ is a fixed positive function, continuous on $[a, b]$.

My question is, do I only need to verify that this definition is in line with axioms of an inner product in order to solve this problem? It seem to be too easy, so I feel like missing something. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the question, I had never encountered the terminology: unitary space.

Comment: my book defines it the same as complex Euclidean space :)

Comment: *complex Euclidean space with an inner product I must add!

Comment: That's a self-adjoint subspace of a weighted $L^2$ space, for a possible shortcut. Otherwise, yes, you just have to check the axioms.

Comment: It is just an introduction to linear spaces so I do not really understand you shortcut, but thanks for confirmation!